# Help with an specific example of a higher derivative Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus, classical-field-theory

I want to find the equation of motion that comes from the following Lagrangian density  $$\mathscr{L}=\mathbf{E}\cdot\left(\nabla^{2}\mathbf{E}\right)$$
where $E_{i}=\partial_{i}\phi\;(i=x,y,z)$ .
In this case the $\phi$ and its 3rd derivatives are the independent variables. The Euler-Lagrange equation contains two terms
$$\partial_{i}\frac{\mathscr{\partial L}}{\partial(\partial_{i}\phi)}$$ and $$\partial_{ijk}\frac{\mathscr{\partial L}}{\partial(\partial_{ijk}\phi)}.$$

For the first term I'm getting
 $$\partial_{i}\frac{\mathscr{\partial L}}{\partial(\partial_{i}\phi)}=\nabla\cdot\left(\nabla^{2}\mathbf{E}\right),$$
a nice scalar function.

===============

Now, Im having problem with the 3rd derivatives term.

QUESTION: Are permutation of the index to be considered independent variables or the same?, e.g, it is $\partial_{xxy}\phi$ the same independent variable as $\partial_{xyx}\phi$?

If different permutations are to be understood as the same, I get the following 
$$\partial_{ijk}\frac{\mathscr{\partial L}}{\partial(\partial_{ijk}\phi)} = \;\partial_{xxx}E_{x}+3\partial_{xyy}E_{x}+3\partial_{xzz}E_{x}
  +3\partial_{xxy}E_{y}+\partial_{yyy}E_{y}+3\partial_{zzy}E_{y}
  +3\partial_{xxz}E_{z}+3\partial_{zyy}E_{z}+\partial_{zzz}E_{z},$$

which doesn't seems to be an scalar.

QUESTION: Is my result correct? If not, why not (obviously)? If yes, then the last expression should be expressed in an scalar combination of $\nabla$ that I'm not seeing it, correct?

EDIT: If,on the other hand, I should only have to consider one permutation of $\partial_{xxy}\phi$, then the result seems to be

$$\partial_{ijk}\frac{\mathscr{\partial L}}{\partial(\partial_{ijk}\phi)} = \;\partial_{xxx}E_{x}+\partial_{xyy}E_{x}+\partial_{xzz}E_{x}
  +\partial_{xxy}E_{y}+\partial_{yyy}E_{y}+\partial_{zzy}E_{y}
  +\partial_{xxz}E_{z}+\partial_{zyy}E_{z}+\partial_{zzz}E_{z}=\nabla\cdot\left(\nabla^{2}\mathbf{E}\right),$$

Comment: ... you know you can integrate by parts, and reduce the problem to first order derivatives only, right?